# Metric signature conventions: minus sign for $x^a$ or $x_a$?

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, conventions

Say I use the metric signature $(-+++)$. Then
$\partial_a=(\partial_0,\partial_i)=(-\partial^0,\partial^i)$,
but
$\partial^a=(\partial^0,\partial^i)=(-\partial_0,\partial_i)$.

The same goes for $p^a$ and $p_a$, I suppose. I know that we need to contract, say, $x^a$ with $p_a$ to give $-x^0p_0+x^ip_i$. So my question is: Does this convention of whether to put ``$-$'' on quantities with superscripts or subscripts apply to all quantities? $x^a$ and $x_a$? $A^a$ and $A_a$?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I think you cleared my confusion already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, when replacing a free index with a specific one, no signs ever get introduced:
\begin{align}
\partial_a & \to (\partial_0, \partial_i) \\
\partial^a & \to (\partial^0, \partial^i).
\end{align}
This holds for all signatures. (On a side note, I'm being pedantic about not using "$=$" signs for a reason - a tensor is not equal to a single, albeit unspecified, component of itself.)

The only question, then, is the relation between $\partial_0$ and $\partial^0$, and between $\partial_i$ and $\partial^i$. In general, again without regard to signature, we have
\begin{align}
\partial_a & = g_{ab} \partial^b \\
\partial^a & = g^{ab} \partial_b.
\end{align}
In special relativity, $g_{ab} = \eta_{ab}$ and $g^{ab} = \eta^{ab}$, where now we need to agree on a signature to conclude
\begin{align}
\partial_0 & = -\partial^0 & \partial_i & = \partial^i \\
\partial^0 & = -\partial_0 & \partial^i & = \partial_i.
\end{align}

Actually, your worry about where to put the signs means you've put in an extra. In fact, we have
$$ x^a p_a = x^0 p_0 + x^1 p_1 + x^2 p_2 + x^3 p_3. $$
This is exactly the same as
$$ x_a p^a = x_0 p^0 + x_1 p^1 + x_2 p^2 + x_3 p^3. $$
The above holds in GR in any signature. If you are in SR and have the $(-,+,+,+)$ signature, then you can write
$$ x^a p_a = -x^0 p^0 + x^1 p^1 + x^2 p^2 + x^3 p^3 $$
or
$$ x^a p_a = -x_0 p_0 + x_1 p_1 + x_2 p_2 + x_3 p_3. $$
Note the negative term only enters when you insist on using the same indices (either upper or lower) for both $x$ and $p$. Also note that these two formulas only hold in SR, where swapping indices at worst introduced a negative. In general,
$$ x^a p_a = g_{ab} x^a p^b, $$
which can have $16$ terms in the sum.

Comment: Clear, concise and complete. +1

Answer (score 5):

Using your metric signature, the metric is:
$$\eta_{\mu\nu}=\begin{pmatrix}-1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

The generic position vector is defined as (in Cartesian) $$x^{\mu}=\begin{pmatrix}t\\x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}$$
And the quantity $x_{\mu}=\eta_{\mu\nu}x^{\nu}$. So you can see that $x_\mu$ becomes the one with a minus sign on $x_0$.

Then, the derivative is defined as:
$$\partial_\mu=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}$$
So you can see that $\partial_0=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ is positive. When you apply the metric, $$\partial^\mu=\eta^{\mu\nu}\partial_\nu=\eta^{\mu\nu}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\nu}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_\mu}$$
and thus $\partial^0$ becomes negative.

So to answer your question, yes the convention applies. Changing a superscript to a subscript is done through applying the metric. $A_a=\eta_{ab}A^b$ and $A^a=\eta^{ab}A_b$ and $\eta^{ab}\eta_{ab}=4$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, indeed it does.

$\\$

Have you taken a maths course on [Metric Spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space) perhaps?

A Metric Space, roughly, is something where we have a notion of how to measure things.

So, for example, [Euclidean Space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_space) is a very fimiliar space, you measure the square of the magnitude of a vector to be

$$ \vec{x} \cdot \vec{x} = (x^1)^2 + (x^2)^2 + (x^3)^2 = (x_1)^2 + (x_2)^2 + (x_3)^2 $$

This could also be written using a [metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_%28mathematics%29) as

$$ \vec{x} \cdot \vec{x} = g_{ij} x^i x^j $$

where $i = 1,2,3$ and $j = 1,2,3$. Here I'm using [Einstein Summation Convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_summation_convention), such that $g_{ij} x^i x^j$ with the $i$ and $j$ repeated like that, one upper and one lower, is shorthand for

$$ g_{ij} x^i x^j = \sum_{i=1}^3 \sum_{j=1}^3 g_{ij} x^i x^j$$

$\\$

So our metric, $g_{ij}$ is just

$$ g_{ij} = \mbox{diag}(+1,+1,+1) $$

that is, when $i=j$ we get $g_{ii} = + 1$, while if $i \neq j$ we get zero, $g_{ij}\vert_{i\neq j} =0$.

$\\$

You'll then see that when raising and lowering indices using the metric like

$$ x^i = g^{ij} x_j \quad \mbox{ or } \quad x_i = g_{ij} x^j $$

That the raised one $x^i$ and the lowered one $x_j$ are the same, since the $g_{ij}$ are each just $+1$.

So that was nice and easy.

$\\$

Now when we move to [Minkowski Space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_space) for [Special Relativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_relativity), it gets a little more complicated. The metric components (the equivalent of the $g_{ij}$) are no longer all $+1$. We usually use $\eta^{\mu \nu}$ for the Minkowski Space metric, where

$$ \eta^{\mu \nu} = \mbox{diag}(-1,+1,+1,+1)  $$

in your convention. (It should be noted that not everyone uses the same set of +1 and -1, so you should always check this and make sure. It can be very fustrating when something doesn't work out because the other guy was using a different sign!).

Anyway, a vector, like $A^{\mu}$ as you ask, can be lowered with the metric tensor like

$$ A_{\mu} = g_{\mu \nu} A^{\nu} $$

So since by definition

$$ A_{\mu} = (A^0, A^i) $$

when we lower the index we get

$$ A_{\mu} = g_{\mu \nu} A^{\nu} = (g_{0 \nu} A^{\nu}, g_{i \nu} A^{\nu}) = \left( \sum_{\nu = 0}^3 g_{0 \nu} A^{\nu}, \sum_{\nu = 0}^3 g_{i \nu} A^{\nu} \right)  $$

But since all the $g_{\mu \nu}$ are zero when $\mu \neq \nu$, the only ones in the sum that are not zero are

$$ A_{\mu} = g_{\mu \nu} A^{\nu} = (g_{0 0} A^{0}, g_{i i} A^{i})  $$

and we know this from the definition of our metric tensor above, namely

$$ A_{\mu} = g_{\mu \nu} A^{\nu} = ((-1) A^{0}, (+1) A^{i}) = (-A^{0}, A^{i}) $$

$\\$

You can use the metric tensor to raise and lower any index, such as, for example,

$$ T_{\mu \nu \rho}^{\; \; \; \; \sigma} = g_{\mu \alpha} g_{\nu \beta} g^{\sigma \gamma} T^{\alpha \beta}_{\; \; \; \rho \gamma} $$

Comment: The metric of GR is not a metric in the sense of metric spaces, it is a metric in the sense of pseudo-Riemannian manifolds (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Riemannian_manifold#Tangent_spaces_and_metric_tensors).

Comment: @joshphysics : I am not exactly sure what you are trying to say, but if it is that a Riemannian manifold is not a metric space as it has a metric tensor as opposed to a metric function, then that would be incorrect. See the fifth sentence of second paragraph of the wikipedia article on [Metric Tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor). Moreover, the tangent space to our GR Lorentzian manifold is indeed a metric space, namely it is Minkowski space locally, which is a pseudo-Euclidean space. See the introductory paragraph in[Metric Space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space).

Comment: On a *connected*, *Riemannian* manifold $M$, one *can* use the metric tensor to define a distance function $d:M\times M\to \mathbb R$ such that the pair $(M,d)$ is a metric space.  In fact $d(p,q)$ if defined as the greatest lower bound of lengths of piecewise smooth curve segments from $p$ to $q$.  On a *pseudo*-Riemannian manifold however, I'm relatively certain that the same cannot be done because the metric tensor has indefinite signature.  In any case, it's important to note that the metric *tensor* is not a metric on the manifold in the sense of metric spaces.

Comment: See, for example, the bullet point at the end of this nLab article: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pseudo-Riemannian+metric